# Is there any integration of the Entity registration module with modal forms?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I'm using the [Entity Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/registration) module for events registration. I want to open the registration forms in the ctools modal.

I checked the [Modal forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module. But on the module page, I can see that it can only work with `login/reset password/user regisration/webform/contact/comment forms`.

So there is any possibility to use these both modules? Or should I look for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Few alternative way may helps you.

[Entity popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_popup) module.

> This module allows you to show an entity in a popup. For flexibility,
>   it doesn't provide any popup plugins itself, but it provides a menu
>   callback that allows you to load the entity into any popup you desire.

[NG Lightbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/ng_lightbox) module:

> Lightbox any Drupal page such as the login page or comment reply.
>       Works with forms out of the box, including webforms, node edit forms and more.
>       Lightweight, only 1.2kbs in D7. D8 uses cores modal.
>       Default responsive theme for the lightbox that can be customised.

Comment: Using these modules, the form will work through ajax? As if there are validation error messages the form will will redirect to the registration page I think.